# eclipse won't overwrite files in the save location

Tags: eclipse, save

Got an assignment due,

Trying to save the files that I've just coded over the original skeleton files, and then move them to my desktop, every time i save all or save as, then click yes to overwrite them in the place i have the project saved, I take them off my computer, and put them onto the desktop, and they are just skeletons that have no work that I have put in them, just what we were given for the original assignment.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are on windows and have the original files open in some editor or such, then windows will not let you overwrite them.  Make sure you don't have them open anywhere.

Comment: Yeah i have made sure of that, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're a fool and are looking in the wrong workspace.